# cutting the wire

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the problem starts off by asking you to devise a formula for N —being the amount of parallel cuts— through a wire bent to form an N shape and the relationship between the amount of wire pieces. It then goes on to say that when N=1 the total wire pieces equal 4 and when N is 2 the total sum is 7 so therefore, what would 142 parallel cuts be? Now I understand that there is a pattern of adding 3 for every Parallel cut but, I'm struggling with creating the formula and I couldn't find anything on the internet that could help break it down.

Comment: "Now I understand that there is a pattern of adding 3 for every Parallel cut"  So if you do $k$ cuts you add $3$ a total of $k$ times and that is....

Answer (score 1):

Now, for any number of parallel cuts, say N>0, the vertices will give you exactly 2 wires, and the two ends will also give you 2, so you have 4 pieces there. Now for any 2 parallel cuts, there will be 3 sections between them, 2 on the straight sides and 1 on diagonal side. So you have (N-1)3 pieces there. In total, therefore, you have (N-1)*3+4 or 3N+1 pieces.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I understand that there is a pattern of adding 3 for every Parallel cut but

Well, that's it then, isn't it?

What do you get if you add $3$ a  $k$ number of *times*?

......

After $k$ cuts you will add $\underbrace{3 + 3+...+3}_{k \text{ times}}= 3\times k$ pieces to your original $1$.

So after $k$ cuts you have $3k + 1$ pieces.

(To me, the *hard* part is understanding why each cut adds three pieces...)

(And that's because once you make the first cut you will three cut ends of the wire sticking out and each cut is in essence cutting off those three tips.)

===old ====

If the corners of the $N$ weren't connect then the one cut would be $6$ and $2$ cuts would be $9$ and three cuts would be.....? (You are basically just cutting the ends off three wires so....)

And $142$ cuts would be...?

But since the corners of the $N$s *are* connected the two corners will each be one piece instead of two then the number of pieces will be...?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy for me to work this out in notation, however the first two examples had a pattern I followed, more from a programming syntax perspective.
for every 1 cut equals 4 pieces.
for every 2 cuts equals 7 pieces.

All I saw was: 
One multiplied by three plus one equals four ($1\cdot3+1=4$)
Two multiplied by three plus one equals seven (2x3+1=7)
Therefore to work out 142 cuts was simply the same pattern:
One hundred and fourty two multiplied by three plus one equals four hundred and twenty seven (142x3+1=427).

It's the logic in between I cannot see :) Just the pattern.

23/02/2020 update:

Ok, thought more on the logic.

So the wire was once one piece, then bent into 3 sections.

Only the first example of one cut introduces the 3 sections as 4 pieces, physically.

For every cut we make, we are splitting by multiplying the original 3 pieces and adding one extra piece.

S AS fixed Original Sections being 3

P AS total Pieces

C AS # of Cuts

Formula as:

P = S(C)+1

Breakdown for first cut:

P = 3x1+1 = 4

Breakdown for two parallel cuts:

P = 3x2+1 = 7

Breakdown for three parallel cuts:

P = 3x3+1 = 10

Breakdown for the 142 parallel cuts:

P = 3x142+1 = 427